# How would I type a command factory function?

Tags: flowtype

Here's a boiled down example of what I'm trying to Flow type. Consider this function...

```
const createCommand = ({
    auth,
    exec,
} => async (...args) => {
    await auth(...args)
    return exec(...args)
}
```

Things I want from Flow typing this function...
* auth and exec are both async functions that have the same input (can be any number of inputs)
* auth is a void function (return Promise since it's async)
* the function returned by createCommand should return the same thing that exec returns (which hopefully the return makes clear)
* if all of this is doable, one more extension! auth and exec must always have a first argument of a particular type!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in Flow right now. I think this kind of typing is called variadic generics. Other useful examples for variadic generics would be typing `bind`, `call`, and `apply` from `Function.prototype`. I'm not sure if Flow has plans to implement this but you can view a [similar issue here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1251). I think TypeScript supports this functionality with [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897).

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here is that you're trying to write a polymorphic function, but you have not annotated it as being polymorphic. Flow always infers functions to be monomorphic. Here's an example using the identity function:

```js
const badIdentity = x => x;
(badIdentity(123): number); // Error - cannot cast string to number
(badIdentity("hello"): string); // Error - cannot cast number to string
```

We want `badIdentity` to be the identity function, which is polymorphic. However, since it's not explicitly annotated with type parameters (i.e. `<...>`), Flow infers it to be monomorphic, and guess the type of `x` based on function calls. In this example, Flow would infer `badIdentity` to be

```js
(x: (number | string)) => (number | string)
```

To fix this, you must provide type parameters.

```js
const goodIdentity = <T>(x: T): T => x;
(goodIdentity(123): number); // Ok
(goodIdentity("hello"): string); // Ok
```

---

Your specific case can also be fixed by adding explicit type parameters to the `createCommand` function

```js
const createCommand = <Args: $ReadOnlyArray<mixed>, Ret>({
    auth,
    exec,
} : {
    auth: (...Args) => Promise<mixed>,
    exec: (...Args) => Ret,
}): (...Args) => Promise<Ret> => async (...args) => {
    await auth(...args)
    return exec(...args)
}
```

[try-flow link](https://flow.org/try/?fbclid=IwAR26LMHe7mz9Djp_k6aSfJ79RvT_C59ZznNJtWuw0yogWJA4nFkF0YhUjlw#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqStYBBAV2wAtQBeUACkgEsAnHALlHWIFsAjAU0YA0oTLzToAJmxyN66AOYBKKgD5QABUaxO9EQDpGvTLGgA3XnQCG0EQtQYceAlVoNm2Nhx78hIsZOHYMvJKlKoADhbMvABicBbYdEw4SuGRIrGw8TS%20GOK2dli4KAbxvADCWpwWEs4APISMcphsACQASrwW4gDy6NAAng2MFv212gAevOLKQh3YyjQA3oigq6AWpGQCK2u8kyjbAL6gbMtr65tsNLo3DU0hqhpaOrxj9JPT2%20d7olc3undMA9QHMjgo-rdGkCVOpNNoRLU5qpQutMP10ChaP9IvcYWc1hZ4BZ6LgNuRrjccUCdqsDNhiIx0KAfigKboqbZDsgxA4DJhiNBcNRip1sOVKtVxEsLuQ2PgiJshCy5U5DgoaABmIQAcm4FgAXtr8og%20QLsLpyLx0DQaCYrMReGxuARoMDFqAecZeLo4HJbfbeEo1UA)

Basically, you have to explicitly annotate `Args` or `Ret` everywhere they appear in the types in order for Flow to recognize those types as polymorphic. If you miss an annotation somewhere then Flow will infer that type to be monomorphic.